# Globalization for asp.net MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently trying to change the language according to the user choice for my website, i have a dropdown that call a method via an ajax action link to change the language settings. The problem is that the language don't change right the way, i have to change to an other page to see a difference. I would like to know if there is a way to refresh the actual page juste like when you press F5 in your browser.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Specifying `true` instructs the browser to always reload from the server instead of potentially using it's cache.

Comment: Thanks Kendaleiv, i show in details the solution for people facing the same issue.

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    function reload(){
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>`


`@Ajax.ActionLink(item.Text,"SwitchLanguage","Language",
                                 new {lang = item.Value }, 
                                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "reload"})`

Comment: Thanks ... this helped me in an unrelated scenario!

Answer (score 0):

Better will be modify the current Url with new language and do a redirect.So it will redirect to same page with updated url.